# List of items not being displayed in Django page

Tags: django, django-views

I am very new to Django and working through the Azure introduction. I am trying to display a list of items from a model on a page in a tabular format. I have tried two different models in different formats, but no matter what I try no items are displayed. I can confirm through the admin interface and the shell I have items in the DB. Below are the urls.py, views.py and html.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('items', views.items_list, name='item_list'),
    path('item/int:pk/',views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import item
from django.http import HttpResponse

def items_list(request):
    items = item.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'item_list.html', {'items': items})

def item_detail(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(item, id=pk)
    context = {'items': item}
    return render(request, 'item_detail.html', context)
```

item_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
item list
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>item list</h2>
<div>Here is the list of registered items</div>
    {% for item in items %}
        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'item_detail' item.id %}">
                {{item.email}}
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

The page that is displayed only shows the table header and not the items in the table. No errors are displayed in the console and while I can run it in debug I don't know enough to know what to look for.

Comment: If you `view source` in your browser page, do you see html for the `div`s in your `{% for...%}` loop?  If so, it's a styling problem. If not, you need to check what is being passed to the template, eg, by putting `print(items)` in your view before the render() and making sure it's populated before being passed as context.

Comment: Thank you SamSparx, you pointed me in the right direction! I had another look through my code and I had a case issue in the view definition. Fixed that and now all good.